# Duvida sobre código HTML junto com JS

Tags: javascript, html

Bom dia galera, estou com uma duvida aqui. Estou fazendo uns exercícios do 'Alura', só que para deixar bem bonito e organizado aqui para mim, resolvi colocar para que ele mostrasse quando executado o index ele mostrasse a pergunta da atividade junto com a resposta, só que na pergunta e resposta tem o código html/js juntos e queria saber de qual maneira posso fazer com que ele apareça na pagina index.

Código com a pergunta e reposta é o seguinte.

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
Atividado Tapando buraco
<br>
Amanda esteve muito ocupada e não teve tempo de finalizar um trabalho em grupo.<br>
 Seus amigos, desesperados, precisam terminar o programa para conseguirem um ponto que pode ajudá-los a passar na matéria. <br>
 O código era o seguinte:
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script>
     document.write ("<br>");
    document.write("O resultado da fórmula é : " + n * (10 / 20)  );
    document.write ("<br>");
</script>


<script>
     document.write ("<br>");
     document.write ( "Resposta da atividade");
     document.write ("<br>");
     document.write ("O resultado da fórmula é :" + (5*(10/20)) + " resul." );
</script>
```

Comment: Você quer é exibir fragmento de código como texto na página?

Comment: isso, exatamente isso.